# How can I remove "," at the end of shell loop?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm a newbie of shell script language

I try to write this loop

```
for ((i=100; i>0; i--));
do
echo -n "\" Hello $i \" , ";
done
```

for the result it will show

> " Hello 100 " , " Hello 99 " , ... " Hello 1 " , <<

but at the end of text have `","`

how can I improve my code to remove it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One-line* solution using `sed` replacement:

```
for i in {100..1}; do echo -n "\" Hello $i \" , "; done | sed 's/,\s*$//g'
```

`{100..1}` - range of numbers from `100` to `1`

`sed 's/,\s*$//g'` - will replace the last comma at the end of the text with empty string

---

The output for an exemplary range `{10..1}` would be as below:

```
" Hello 10 " , " Hello 9 " , " Hello 8 " , " Hello 7 " , " Hello 6 " , " Hello 5 " , " Hello 4 " , " Hello 3 " , " Hello 2 " , " Hello 1 "
```

Comment: Removing something that should not be there in the first place is a bad practice. I recommend to simply not print the comma after the last line.

Comment: @hek2mgl, performing `if` condition on each iteration is not good practice(in case of big ranges, let's say `{10000..1}`) if it's about just removing the trailing comma

Comment: Performing `if` check on each iteration is not good practice, replacing it with a regular expression check on all the output is not good either.

Answer (score 2):

Print the separator *before* the item, the separator should be null initially, and then set unconditionally after the first iteration.  It is explicit, easy to understand, and efficient.

```
sep=
for ((i=100; i>0; i--)); do
  echo -n "$sep\" Hello $i \""
  sep=" , "
done
```

As suggested by @CharlesDuffy you could use printf (a bash builtin) instead of echo -n

```
sep=
for ((i=100; i>0; i--)); do
  printf "$sep\" Hello $i \""
  sep=" , "
done
```

Comment: `printf '%s"Hello %s "' "$sep" "$i"` would be better practice than relying on `echo -n` -- the POSIX spec for `echo` makes behavior with `-n` completely undefined, rather than defining the behavior you expect here (where no newline is printed).

Comment: See the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Answer (score 0):

Separate commma's `echo` from the rest, and put in an if condition to check for last repetition...

```
for ((i=100; i>0; i--));
do
  echo -n "\" Hello $i \"";
  if ($i!=1) then
   echo -n ","; 
  endif
done
```

Comment: I tried this but it show "Hello 100" [i!=1]: command not found

Comment: @ChanathipChuayboonchum  what kind of shell is it? is it `bash` ? Beacuse the `if` that I gave was using `bash` syntax...

Comment: I use linux shell script.

Comment: If requires spaces around brackets `[ i!=1 ]`.Especially for such simple if you can do it like `[ i!=1 ] && echo -n ","`

Comment: Oh man it worked! but it still has "," after 1 https://www.mx7.com/view2/zJ9wy1VF0Hduknds

Comment: @ChanathipChuayboonchum oh ok forgot $ befoe i , make it $i

Comment: Yahhh! Finally Thank you so much!!

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, not just spaces around the brackets, also spaces between the operators. `[ i!=1 ]` is always true, because it's checking whether `"i!=1"` is a non-empty string (which is is). If you wanted to know the result of `[ "$i" != 1 ]`, that would be a different test.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (late) answer, you don't need *remove the last `,`* but you can contruct the output without it using the `paste` command, like:

```
for ((i=10; i>0; i--));
do
    printf '"Hello %d"\n' $i;
    #or     echo "\"Hello $i\""
done | paste -sd, -
```

output:

```
"Hello 10","Hello 9","Hello 8","Hello 7","Hello 6","Hello 5","Hello 4","Hello 3","Hello 2","Hello 1"
```

or just:

```
printf '"Hello  %d"\n' {10..1} | paste -sd, -
```

with same output